# Answering Dialoges with Bash

Tags: debian, bash, debian-jessie, dialog

I need to automatically answer all dialoge (blue screenish Text GUI) questions when running **dpkg-reconfigure exim4** as I have a bash script which will run on many servers.

Is there some way to automatically input text, press enter and select yes/no?

Comment: See 'expect' scripts

Comment: @JacobEvans Are they compatible with dialoges (these blue screen questions?)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/96215/52243 answered here

Comment: Maybe you would like to have a look at [configuration management software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management#Operating_System_configuration_management).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dpkg-reconfigure exim4 is just an interface to easily create the text configuration files for exim. There is no advantage to finding a way to answer the questions automatically (if you did have to do that, `expect` would be a valid choice).

If you have a lot of servers you should provide or generate the files in /etc/exim directly. You could, for example, do this on one server, and the copy /etc/exim to the other servers. You just need to make sure that the hostname is taken from the real hostname and not overridden in the files.

Comment: exim4 was just an example. But you helped me out a lot. I did not know that all this (exim4 configs)  can be configured manually. Thanks.

Comment: In general, in Linux, *everything* can be configured manually :) If exim was just an example, and you want to do unattended / automatic installation of a lot of debian packages, then @allo has a useful point.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use dialogs, if it's just for dpkg.

Have a look at:

- debconf-set-selections
- DEBIAN_FRONTEND

http://www.microhowto.info/howto/perform_an_unattended_installation_of_a_debian_package.html